# How to judge a partition is balanced or unbalanced?

Tags: unbalanced-classes

Suppose we distributed $100$ coins to $10$ persons and the $i$-th person got ${x}_{i}$ coins, how to judge the distribution $X=\{{x}_{1}, {x}_{2}, ..., {x}_{n}\}$ (e.g., $X=\{5, 20, 15, 5, 10, 10, 10, 15, 5, 5\}$) is (almost) balanced or not? Is there a mathematical definition or empirical criterion of the unbalancedness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways you could measure unbalancedness/inequality. The first one to mind is the entropy, but you could alternatively use any of the many ways [economic inequality is measured](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Income_inequality_metrics) (like the Gini coefficient).

Comment: Great, I will use Geni index since it has different levels of inequality.

Answer (score 0):

There were also two measures developed by Ahrens/Pincus (1981) for the unbalancedness of (panel) data sets, which would also work in your case.

If a data set is balanced, the measures equal one and the more unbalanced the data, the lower the measures (but >0).

However, use of that measure seems not very widespread. Most often, it is found in econometric context (if at all). An implementation is e. g. in <s>the current development version</s> latest CRAN versions of the package `plm` for panel data for the `R` environment (`punbalancedness` is the function).

Reference is:

> Ahrens/Pincus, On Two Measures of Unbalancedness in a One-Way Model
>   and Their Relation to Efficiency, Biometrical Journal, Volume 23,
>   Issue 3, pages 227–235, 1981.